# A sentence made with "please"

Tags: word-usage

**Restaurants aim to please.**

In the sentence, "please" is used as an **intransitive**, meaning "to make someone happy or satisfied". Does the sentence make sense to you?

Comment: Sure.  To paraphrase, "The goal of restaurants is to satisfy."

Comment: I did not read this question until after I wrote my answer to your question about *pleasing.* There I mentioned the phrase 'willing to please'. It serves a similar funtion as 'aims to please' and shows that both phrases are commonly used. One could say that the restaurant is 'willing to please' its customers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. "Aim to please" is a normal English idiom, at least in the U.S. It's often heard in the sentence "We aim to please."